# How to know if a flag is enabled on QtGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, isenabled, enum-flags

I am trying to make an if condition on whether the flag 'ItemIsMovable' of a QGraphicsItem is enabled.

Ideally something like:

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw

item = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(1, 1, 10, 10)

if 'ItemIsMovable' in item.flags():
    do things ...
```

Here I am using the method `QGraphicsItem::flags()` that returns the object `QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlags` which I don't know what to do with: it has no attributes, no methods.

I have read the Qt documentation and I could not find a method that tells me if a specific flag is enabled or not. I was looking for a function like *QGraphicsItem::isFlagEnabled(flag) --> bool*.

I have tried to iterate over `QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlags` but I get the error that it is not iterable.

**Is there any way to get the status of a flag, enabled or disabled?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bitwise operator "and" (&).

```
if item.flags() & QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable:
```

Comment: I had the same problem and now I see the solution, Thanks. Could you please tell me how did you find this out? I read the doc but I found nothing, so is there any link that can help me out exploring these things?

Comment: @UncleBob any qtflags type is essentialy an integer number (a list of bits), each bit represents boolean value (presence or absence of quality),  "bitwise and" is standart way to check whether specific bit is on (1) or off (0), look for example at [GraphicsItemFlag](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum)